# Preg replace not working with captured params and <

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

When I add the less than "<" symbol

```
$str = 'test';
$str = preg_replace('@(.*)@isu', '<$1', $str);
echo $str; // outputs ""
```

It should output `<test`, but instead outputs nothing.

It works fine when I don't add the character.

```
$str = 'test';
$str = preg_replace('@(.*)@isu', '$1', $str);
echo $str; // outputs "test"
```

I tried escaping it

```
$str = 'test';
$str = preg_replace('@(.*)@isu', '<\\\\$1', $str);
echo $str; // outputs "<\test"
```

I was unable to find anything about this in the php manual while google just spits out unrelated SO questions.

I would like to know why this does not work?

PHP 5.4.22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are checking the outputs from the browser. That's why its doing such behaviour. From the console it works perfectly. So, I believe you'll find everything when you view the source of html from browser.

Also, you can replace the `<` with `&lt;`

Comment: Good idea, browsers interpret < as html, but my source is blank :(

Comment: after I set the `Content-type: text/html` I saw it with the original code I had so marking this as the accepted answer

Comment: Just so that future readers are well aware, original code in question doesn't *work perfectly* as it makes input as **`<test<`** instead of intended **`<test`**

Answer (score 3):

Use line `start and end anchors` in your regex:

```
$str = 'test';
$str = preg_replace('@^(.*)$@isu', '<$1', $str);
echo $str;
```

OR use `.+`:

```
$str = preg_replace('@(.+)@isu', '<$1', $str);
```

OR with `.*` specify max replacement count:

```
$str = preg_replace('@(.*)@isu', '<$1', $str, 1);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<test
```

Problem is by using `.*` `preg_replace` is matching and replacing the input string twice, once for the whole input string and once for the end (empty string).

Comment: I want it to match substrings, not whole strings

Comment: Then use `.+` as I suggested

Comment: `... '@(.+)@isu', '<$1'...` outputs "" for me for some reason

Comment: Are you implying my PHP version has a bug or something?

Comment: No I'm not implying that but it may be due to different input string than the one in your example. btw is `$str = preg_replace('@(.*)@isu', '<$1', $str, 1);` working better for you?

Comment: Yes! got it to work!! Thank you! now to figure out why

Comment: Great to know you were able to resole this issue. @JakeGould: Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Unclear on how `<\\\\$1` would escape the less than (`<`) symbol? Have you tried this?

```
$str = 'test';
$str = preg_replace('@(.*)@isu', '\<$1', $str);
echo $str;
```

**EDIT** Since it’s been discovered you can view the `<test` in the source code of a browser, I adjusted my code as follows to make the output human readable in a browser:

```
$str = 'test';
$str = preg_replace('@(.*)@isu', "<$1", $str);
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities($str);
echo '</pre>';
```

But that outputs:

```
<test<
```

As the user `anubhava` explains, you can add a `1` to the end of the `preg_replace` to return only the first match:

```
$str = preg_replace('@(.*)@isu', "<$1", $str, 1);
```

Which would then output the following which is what the original poster desires:

```
<test
```

Comment: `preg_replace('@(.*)@isu', '\<$1', $str)` outputs "\"

Comment: "<test", added to question